# TypeScript: How to get typeof 'OR' type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a React Hook that accepts two completely different array types, and I am wondering if I can somehow get their types 'Chat[]' or 'NewGroupMember[]' in my code. I was thinking of passing a 'type' value into my function so I could keep track and check in my switch case statement but that throws an error. If is there any way, let me know!

```
export function useSort<PossibleType>(
    delay: number,
    array: PossibleType extends "MainPanel.tsx" ? Chat[] : PossibleType extends "NewGroup.tsx" ? NewGroupMember[] : [],

    type: PossibleType
) {
    const [rawInput, setRawInput] = useState("");
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState<Chat[]>([]);

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setRawInput(e.target.value.toLowerCase());

    const delayedInput = useDebounce(rawInput, delay);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!delayedInput || delayedInput.length <= 1) return setFilteredData(array);

        let result = [];

        switch (type) {
            case "MainPanel.tsx":
                result = array.filter((data) => data.chatName.search(delayedInput) != -1);
                break;
            case "NewGroup.tsx":
                result = array.filter((data) => data.email.search(delayedInput) != -1);
            default:
                result = array;
        }

        setFilteredData(result);
    }, [delayedInput, array]);

    return { rawInput, handleChange, delayedInput, filteredData };
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do it run different pieces of code depending on what type is passed into the function ie function overloading. Unfortunately typescript does not add compile time function overloading or equivalent methods. You would have to do it the same way as in javascript for example using `instanceof` or `typeof` etc.